# Android Espresso testing. Get IndexOutOfBoundsException when testing ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, matcher, android-espresso

I got following exception when I was testing a ListView with customized object and Espresso

```
I/TestRunner: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:997)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterViewProtocols$StandardAdapterViewProtocol.getDataInAdapterView(AdapterViewProtocols.java:93)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterDataLoaderAction.perform(AdapterDataLoaderAction.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        ArrayList<Person> items = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            items.add(new Person("name"+i, "desc"+i));
        }
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                textView.setText("" + position);
            }
        };
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
    }
}
```

My adapter class ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>{

    private final List<Person> _products;
    private final int _layout;

    public ListViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, List<Person> products) {
        super(context, resource);
        _layout = resource;
        _products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertview;
        if(convertview==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(_layout, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.productName)).setText(_products.get(position)._name);
        ((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(_products.get(position)._description);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return _products.size();
    }
}
```

The layout file for MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.seanshi.testespresso2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout file for the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productName"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The app does work well

[image]

Then I added following test class in "androidTest" folder

```
package com.example.seanshi.testespresso2;

import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.BoundedMatcher;
import android.support.test.filters.SmallTest;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onData;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class ListViewTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testListView()
    {
        // withItemContent() is a customized matcher
        onData(withItemContent("name1")).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.myListView)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("1")));
    }

    public static Matcher<Object> withItemContent(final String expectedText) {
        checkNotNull(expectedText);
        return withItemContent(equalTo(expectedText));
    }

    public static Matcher<Object> withItemContent(final Matcher<String> itemTextMatcher) {
        checkNotNull(itemTextMatcher);
        return new BoundedMatcher<Object, Person>(Person.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(Person person) {
                return itemTextMatcher.matches(person._name);
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with item content: "+itemTextMatcher.toString());
                itemTextMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The I got the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when I run this espresso test.

I checked variables values in debug mode, here are values in android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterViewProtocols$StandardAdapterViewProtocol.getDataInAdapterView()

```
@Override
public Iterable<AdaptedData> getDataInAdapterView(AdapterView<? extends Adapter> adapterView) {
  List<AdaptedData> datas = Lists.newArrayList();
  for (int i = 0; i < adapterView.getCount(); i++) {        // getCount() return 10
    int position = i;
    Object dataAtPosition = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);    // but getItemAtPosition(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException 
    datas.add(
        new AdaptedData.Builder()
          .withDataFunction(new StandardDataFunction(dataAtPosition, position))
          .withOpaqueToken(position)
          .build());
  }
  return datas;
}
```

Does anybody know why I got the IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the way, here is the content of Person class.

    public class Person {
        public String _name;
        public String _description;

        public Person(String name, String desc){ 
            _name = name;
            _description = desc;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. It is because I defined a new List variable in my adapter and didn't set value on the variable "List mObjects" in the base class ArrayAdapter.